# How to change a layout background image depending on Dark/Light theme?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-night-mode

I've got two images. I want to do so: when user opens an app with a Light theme - the first image is being used as a background for layouts. When user opens the app with a Dark theme - the second image is being used as a background for layouts.

To solve this problem with text colors, we can just use **styles.xml** and **colors-day/night.xml** and one line of code: `<item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>`

I've tried to the same with images and two **styles** files: `<item name="android:background">@drawable/day</item>`

**But this feature applies background to each element on a screen, not only to the main layouts.**

I know, that I can do it programatically by changing a background with if statements and `layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day/night);`

But maybe it can be done with XML as in the case of the text color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To solve this problem with text colors, we can just use styles.xml and
> colors-day/night.xml and one line of code: @color/textColor

You need to do the same thing, but instead of `res/values/colors.xml`, it should be done on the drawable `res/drawable/day`

So, you'll have a `drawable` & `drawable-night` folders in the `res` directory each of which should have a unique version of the `day` image with the same name.

They should look like in Android Studio (Android preview):

[image]

And normally use the the attribute `name="android:background">@drawable/day</item>`